# Disclosure Buttons, icons don't display in FirstLevelController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have written the following code for a FirstLevelController implementation file, but the Disclosure Buttons, icons don't display in the view. Have checked the code, but can't figure out what's wrong.

FirstLevelController.m:

```
#import "BiDFirstLevelController.h"
#import "BidSecondLevelController.h"
#import "BiDDisclosureButtonController.h"



@implementation BiDFirstLevelController
@synthesize controllers;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"First Level";
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    // Disclosure button
    BiDDisclosureButtonController *disclosureButtonController = [[BiDDisclosureButtonController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    disclosureButtonController.title = @"Disclosure Buttons";
    disclosureButtonController.rowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"disclosureButtonControllerIcon.png"];
    [array addObject:disclosureButtonController];
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.controllers = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.controllers count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *FirstLevelCell = @"FirstLevelCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstLevelCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelCell];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    BiDSecondLevelController *controller = [controllers objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.textLabel.text = controller.title;
    cell.imageView.image = controller.rowImage;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    BiDSecondLevelController *nextController = [self.controllers objectAtIndex:row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: are you retaining or somehow getting ownership the rowImage property inside BiDDisclosureButtonController?

Comment: The rowImage property is declared and synthesized in the BiDSecondLevelController, which is the superclass for BiDDisclosureButtonController

Comment: being synthesized is nowhere even remotely close to owning the object.

Comment: OK, but why doesn't "Disclosure Buttons" show up in the title even though the method is defined in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: It's most likely (null).  NSLog it in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, with NSLog(@"%@", controller.rowImage);

Comment: Strange. When I tried to do the NSLog, got an error message: Expression result unused (referring to rowImage)

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` returns 0, which means the table view should always be empty. Since returning 0 from this method doesn't make sense, I guess it's a typo.

Comment: Changed it to "return [self.controllers count];" but the same problem persists.